# Does the deprecation of Facebook's offline_access affect "publish_stream"?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

[offline-access-deprecation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/)

As of today, If I ask for `publish_stream` permission, can I keep this access token and continue to use it forever? (or do I have to renew it every xxx days)?

Will I be OK if I just use `publish_stream`?

Also, I got this back from the response:

```
access_token=AAAEpyvU...8KktpSub&expires=3673
```

- What does `"expires"` mean? There are 3673 seconds remaining?
- What's the point of having an access token if it expires in 3673 seconds?

Comment: Will all obtained user tokens have 60 day expirations? I didn't see anyting mentioning the new expiration times. Before without Offline access it seemed that tokens expired the same day? Does anyone know what the previous expiration length was before the changes to dep offline access.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Publishing To User's Wall Without Being Online/Logged-in - Facebook Sharing Using Graph API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4814432/publishing-to-users-wall-without-being-online-logged-in-facebook-sharing-usin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `publish_stream` is a special permission.  Once a user grants it, then you have unlimited offline access without needing the offline access to publish to their stream. See:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

> **publish_stream**    Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's stream and to the streams of the user's friends.
>   With this permission, you can publish content to a user's feed at any
>   time, without requiring offline_access. **However, please note that Facebook recommends a user-initiated sharing model.**

Comment: I'm still getting expiration even with the publish_stream. {"error":{"message":"Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1327309200. The current unix time is 1327310423.","type":"OAuthException"}}

Comment: You can't use an expired token for anything.  You need to new up an **app** access token to write when offline.

Comment: what do you mean "new up an APP access token"?  All I know is that I have that user's access token for my app...and it expired, even though the documentation clearly states it should NOT expire when you have publish_stream permission.

Comment: For APP access tokens, please read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/

offline access were allowing users to get life time access but now fb has changed.so every access token now have 60 days expiration time,If you don't use offline_access it will expire with an hour or whatever you will get in  expires=3673 value.Its in second.

Thanks